# Zoom In/Out image on the same view

Tags: ios, swift, zooming, pinchzoom

I want to set Zoom In/Out two images on the same view. On Zoom viewForZooming method is called. Can I detect which image I am zooming and zoom that particular image only?

Comment: Post your code and let us know what have you done!

Comment: func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {            if(scrollViewFirstCV.tag==1)
            {
                return self.firstCVimageView
            }
            else
            
            {
                return self.secondCVimageView
            }
}